# Going deeper with pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for set partitioning

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms, partitions

If I have a set of (edit) **positive** integers, and I'm sure that the [pseudo-polynomial time algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_algorithm) for partitioning the problem will not give me an answer - what would I do next?

To illustrate this problem let's take a look at this example: {`100,1,2,3`}.

The p-p algorithm will give an answer *False*, and then I can end with result: This set can be partitioned into two set with difference `100-6 = 94`

(The `6` is the last result from p-p algorithm on with [`_`][`vector.size()`] = *True*, the `106` is the sum of all digits).

But what if I really would like to know the maximum by sum two-split of this set in which every subset has the same sum - for example the result that I'm looking for should be `3`. This set - {`100,1,2,3`} can be split (by bypassing the `100`) into two subset with the same sum - {`1,2`} and {`3`}.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Why "106-6" - where does 106 come from? Should it be "100-6=94"?

Comment: You are right. Edited after 5 years (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the dynamic programming algorithm to handle this variant. Suppose that the weights are $w_1,\ldots,w_n$. You are looking for a vector $x \in \{0,\pm 1\}^n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i w_i = 0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| w_i$ is as large as possible. This suggests two possible approaches. The first approach is to construct a large table keeping track of all possible pairs of values $(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i w_i, \sum_{i=1}^m |x_i| w_i)$, where $x_1,\ldots,x_m \in \{0,\pm 1\}^m$. This leads to an $O(nM^2)$ algorithm, compared to the $O(nM)$ subset-sum or partition algorithms.

The second approach is to explicitly list all vectors $x$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i w_i = 0$ (using dynamic programming), and choose the one maximizing $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| w_i$. This takes time $O(nM + nS)$, where $S$ is the number of vectors $x$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i w_i = 0$. In practice $S$ might be small enough for this approach to be practical.

Comment: It should be more simple if I know that all of the numers are positive integers and the sum S is less then 10^6.

Comment: could you please help with this second approach and write down the simple pseudo code with I can fallow. Thank you.

Comment: No, writing pseudocode is your job.

Comment: Ok, but I'm just wondering about the proccess of filling the table. Should I fill it with minimal value of previous states (set with less numbers) + {-1,0,1}*(next w_i) and after that backtracking the result that have sum of all = 0?

Comment: You should keep track of all possible values of $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i w_i$ at any given point. Whenever you find that $0$ is possible, you go back and construct the corresponding $x$s. That's the basic idea.

Comment: So the table will have size of `M`x`n` where M is the sum of all the integers, and n is the number of ints? Or maybe 2M because the number can be also negative?

Comment: You can probably make do with $M$ due to symmetry (if $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i w_i = 0$ then $\sum_{i=1}^m (-x_i) w_i = 0$), but it's probably a better idea to allow negative sums (so the table is $n\times 2M$).